# Sort by price wpdb

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, sort, page-specific-settings

I have a page on my wordpress to search for tires everything works fine but I would have liked to know how to add an extra column to sort them also by price.

They can already be sorted by size and type... But I can't find a solution for the price.

Thanks in advance !

Here is the code :

```
    <?php
    $resultLargura = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT wp_t.name FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS wp_tt
                                            INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms AS wp_t ON wp_t.term_id = wp_tt.term_id 
                                            WHERE wp_tt.taxonomy = 'pa_largeur'ORDER BY wp_t.name ASC");

    $resultAltura = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT wp_t.name FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS wp_tt
                                            INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms AS wp_t ON wp_t.term_id = wp_tt.term_id 
                                            WHERE wp_tt.taxonomy = 'pa_hauteur' ORDER BY wp_t.name ASC");

                                        
    $resultDiametro = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT wp_t.name FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS wp_tt
                                            INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms AS wp_t ON wp_t.term_id = wp_tt.term_id 
                                            WHERE wp_tt.taxonomy = 'pa_diametre' ORDER BY wp_t.name ASC");

    $resultTipoPneu = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT wp_t.name FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS wp_tt
                                            INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms AS wp_t ON wp_t.term_id = wp_tt.term_id 
                                            WHERE wp_tt.taxonomy = 'pa_type-de-pneu' ORDER BY wp_t.name");

    $resultDePneu = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT wp_t.name FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS wp_tt
                                            INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms AS wp_t ON wp_t.term_id = wp_tt.term_id 
                                            WHERE wp_tt.taxonomy = 'pa_marque-pneus' ORDER BY wp_t.name");

    $resultDePneus = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT wp_t.name FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS wp_tt
                                            INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms AS wp_t ON wp_t.term_id = wp_tt.term_id 
                                            WHERE wp_tt.taxonomy = 'pa_categories-de-pneus' ORDER BY wp_t.name");
    




?>

<form class="form-tires" action="/resultados-da-pesquisa" method ="GET">
    <h3 style="color: #222 !important">Recherche par dimension</h3>
    <label class="input floatleft"> 
        <select class="fullwidth floatleft" <?php /*required*/?> name="largura">
            <option value="">Largeur</option>
            <?php
                foreach( $resultLargura as $value ) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $value->name; ?>"><?php echo $value->name; ?></option>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label class="input floatleft">
        <select class="fullwidth floatleft" <?php /*required*/?>  name="altura">
            <option value="">Hauteur</option>
            <?php
                foreach( $resultAltura as $value ) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $value->name; ?>"><?php echo $value->name; ?></option>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label class="input floatleft">
        <select class="fullwidth floatleft" <?php /*required*/?>  name="diametro">
            <option value="">Diamètre</option>
            <?php
                foreach( $resultDiametro as $value ) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $value->name; ?>"><?php echo $value->name; ?></option>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </label>
    <div class="pneu-detail"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/pneusahc.png"></div>
    <label class="fullwidth floatleft">
        <select class="fullwidth floatleft" required name="tipoPneu">
            <?php
                foreach( $resultTipoPneu as $value ) { ?>
                
                    <option value="<?php echo $value->name; ?>"><?php echo $value->name; ?></option>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
            
        </select>
    </label>
    <label class="fullwidth floatleft">
        <select class="fullwidth floatleft" required name="DePneu">
            
            <?php
                foreach( $resultDePneu as $value ) { ?>
                
                    <option value="<?php echo $value->name; ?>"><?php echo $value->name; ?></option>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
            
        </select>
    </label>
    
    

    
    
    <label class="fullwidth floatleft">
        <option  style="color: black; font-weight: bold; ">Plus d'indications :</option>
        <select type="checkbox" class="fullwidth floatleft"  name="DePneus">
            <option value="">Aucun</option>
            <?php
                foreach( $resultDePneus as $value ) { ?>
                
                    <option value="<?php echo $value->name; ?>"><?php echo $value->name; ?></option>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
            
        </select>
    </label>
    
        
    <label class="fullwidth floatleft">
        <option  style="color: black; font-weight: bold; ">Choix du prix :</option>
        <select type="checkbox" class="fullwidth floatleft"  name="posts_this_price">
            <option value="">Aucun</option>
            <?php
                foreach( $posts_this_price as $value ) { ?>
                
                    <option value="<?php echo $value->name; ?>"><?php echo $value->name; ?></option>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
            
        </select>
    </label>
    
    

    
    <input type="submit" value="RECHERCHE" name="PESQUISAR" class="fullwidth floatleft">            
</form> 


And the other page : 


    <?php 



    $optionLargura = isset($_GET['largura']) ? $_GET['largura'] : false;
    $optionAltura = isset($_GET['altura']) ? $_GET['altura'] : false;
    $optionDiametro = isset($_GET['diametro']) ? $_GET['diametro'] : false;
    $optionTipoPneu = isset($_GET['tipoPneu']) ? $_GET['tipoPneu'] : false; 
    $marqueDePneu = isset($_GET['DePneu']) ? $_GET['DePneu'] : false; 
    $catDePneus = isset($_GET['DePneus']) ? $_GET['DePneus'] : false; 

    $coin="CHF";
   

            $tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
            if ($optionLargura!='')
            {
                $tax_query[] =  array(
                    'taxonomy'        => 'pa_largeur',
                    'field'           => 'slug',
                    'terms'           =>  array($optionLargura),
                    'operator'        => 'IN',
                );
            }
            if ($optionAltura!='')
            {
                $tax_query[] =  array(
                    'taxonomy'        => 'pa_hauteur',
                    'field'           => 'slug',
                    'terms'           =>  array($optionAltura),
                    'operator'        => 'IN',
                );
            }
            if ($optionDiametro!='')
            {
                $tax_query[] =  array(
                    'taxonomy'        => 'pa_diametre',
                    'field'           => 'slug',
                    'terms'           =>  array($optionDiametro),
                    'operator'        => 'IN',
                );
            }
            if ($optionTipoPneu!='')
            {
                $tax_query[] =  array(
                    'taxonomy'        => 'pa_type-de-pneu',
                    'field'           => 'slug',
                    'terms'           =>  array($optionTipoPneu),
                    'operator'        => 'IN',
                );
            }

              if ($marqueDePneu!='')
            {
                $tax_query[] =  array(
                    'taxonomy'        => 'pa_marque-pneus',
                    'field'           => 'slug',
                    'terms'           =>  array($marqueDePneu),
                    'operator'        => 'IN',
                );
            }

                          if ($catDePneus!='')
            {
                $tax_query[] =  array(
                    'taxonomy'        => 'pa_categories-de-pneus',
                    'field'           => 'slug',
                    'terms'           =>  array($catDePneus),
                    'operator'        => 'IN',
                    
                );
            }

             

if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { // 'page' is used instead of 'paged' on Static Front Page
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}

    $args  = array( 
                 'post_type'           => array('product', 'product_variation'),
                'post_status'         => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
                'paged'          => $paged,
                'tax_query'      => $tax_query,
                'orderby' => 'price',
                 'order' => 'asc',
                            
                  );


    $prods=new WP_Query($args);

        if( $prods->have_posts() ){

                $content = '<form class="cart" action="https://ahcor-autoshop.ch/panier" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" wtx-context="D6ECEB0A-195E-4229-9B5D-1A13E3D7E5AF">';
                

            
            

            while($prods->have_posts()) : 
                $product=$prods->the_post();
                $content .= '<div class="search-col" id="search-product-'.get_the_ID().'">';

                            $attachment_url='<div class="w10 floatleft"><img alt="' . get_the_title() . '" src="https://ahcor-autoshop.ch/wp-content/uploads/pneusahc.png" width="80"></div>';
                            $attachment_id=get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());
                            if($attachment_id){
                                $post_attachment_url=wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
                                if($post_attachment_url)$attachment_url='<div class="w15 floatleft"><img alt="' . get_the_title() . '" src="'.$post_attachment_url.'" width="80"></div>';
                            }
                            $content.=$attachment_url;

   

            
            
            
                            //$content .= '<div class="w60 floatleft"><a href="https://ahcor-autoshop.ch/produit/'.$row->post_name.'/">' . $row->post_title . '</a>';
                            $content .= '<div class="w60 floatleft"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
                            $content .= '<div class="fullwidth floatleft"><small class="inline floatleft">Tags</small></div>';

                            $price=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_regular_price',true);
                            if(date("Y-m-d") != "2020-12-30")
                            {
            
                              
                                $calcAscTotal= $price ;

                                $content .= '<h3 style="color:#d52b1e;"><del style="opacity: .5; display: inline-block; margin: 15px;color: #545454;"></del> CHF '.round($calcAscTotal, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP).' .- '.'</h3>'; 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $content .= '<h3><small>Seulement</small> '. $price.' CHF.- '.'</h3>'; 
                            }
                            $content .= '</div>'; 
                            $content .= '<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value='. get_the_ID() .' class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt w20 floatright">Panier</button>'; 
                            //$content .= '</div>'; 

                $content.='</div>';
          
           endwhile; 
            
    

           $content.= '<a onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;" href="#" class="text-red center-el bold" style="font-size:2em; padding: 20px 0">Retour</a>';
           $content.='</form>';

        }
        else{
            $content.="<h2 class='text-center'>".__('Aucun résultat trouvé','ahcor-autoshop').".</h2>";
            $content.= '<a onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;" href="#" class="text-red center-el bold" style="font-size:2em; padding: 20px 0">Retour</a>';
        }



                
          if($content != "" )echo $content;
            





     if ($prods->max_num_pages > 1) : // custom pagination  
       
        $orig_query = $wp_query; // fix for pagination to work
        $wp_query = $prods;
        ?>
        <nav class="prev-next-posts" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; padding: 20px;">
             <div class="next-posts-link" class="text-red center-el bold" style="font-size:2em;" >
                <?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Précédent' ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="prev-posts-link" class="text-red center-el bold" style="font-size:2em; text-align: right;">
                <?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Suivant', $prods->max_num_pages ); ?>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <?php
        $wp_query = $orig_query; // fix for pagination to work
        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>


        <form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get" value="pneus">
    <select name="orderby" class="orderby" aria-label="Commande">
                    <option value="menu_order" selected="selected">Tri par défaut</option>
                    <option value="popularity">Tri par popularité</option>
                    <option value="rating">Tri par notes moyennes</option>
                    <option value="date">Tri du plus récent au plus ancien</option>
                    <option value="price">Tri par tarif croissant</option>
                    <option value="price-desc">Tri par tarif décroissant</option>
            </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="paged" value="1">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 $args  = array( 
                 'post_type'           => array('product', 'product_variation'),
                'post_status'         => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
                'paged'          => $paged,
                'tax_query'      => $tax_query,
                'orderby' => 'price',
                 'order' => 'asc',
                            
                  );
```

New code

```
  $orderby = $_GET['orderby'] ?? '';
   
  $args  = array( 
                'post_type'           => array('product', 'product_variation'),
                'post_status'         => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
                'paged'          => $paged,
                'tax_query'      => $tax_query
             );
                  
  if ($orderby == 'price') {
    
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        
        $args['meta_key'] = '_price';
        
        $args['order'] = 'asc';
  
  } elseif ($orderby == 'price-desc'){
        
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        
        $args['meta_key'] = '_price';
        
        $args['order'] = 'desc';
        
  } elseif ($orderby == 'menu_order') {
    
    // sort menu order
    
  } elseif ($orderby == 'popularity') {
    
    // sort popularity
    
  } elseif ($orderby == 'rating') {
    
    // sort rating
    
  } elseif ($orderby == 'date') {
    
    // sort date
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much its working ! I have an other question, how can i link this code to my page ? Its take all product on my website. Thank you again !

Comment: `<form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get" value="pneus">
 <select name="orderby" class="orderby" aria-label="Commande">
     <option value="menu_order" selected="selected">Tri par défaut</option>
     <option value="popularity">Tri par popularité</option>
     <option value="rating">Tri par notes moyennes</option>
     <option value="date">Tri du plus récent au plus ancien</option>
     <option value="price">Tri par tarif croissant</option>
     <option value="price-desc">Tri par tarif décroissant</option>
   </select>
 <input type="hidden" name="paged" value="1">
 </form>`

Comment: @MourcelyQuentin If this issue is resolved, close it. For a new question, create a new one

Comment: Its not really resolved so its better to keep this alive !

Comment: @MourcelyQuentin change the current question. I do not understand what you want to get

Comment: Im sorry.. ! So. I just want to make a filter like "sort by price asc and desc" , but i didnt find how i can make this with the code above.

Comment: @MourcelyQuentin I changed the answer. did I understand correctly?